# learnyounode exercise 9 - output is showing undefined, problems understanding async or the logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I've been struggling with the `JUGGLING ASYNC` task on `learnyounode`. As far as I can tell, I'm doing things *almost* right and it looks like the issue sits somewhere with the async compounded by myself trying to avoid  `bl` or other modules. I did the previous task without another module and would like to continue this trend.

```
const http = require('http');
const url = process.argv[2];

let content = [];
let count = 0;

const arguments = process.argv;
let urlArray = arguments.filter(function pullUrls(element, index, array) {
    return index >= 2;
});

function printResults() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(content[i]);
    }
}

function httpGet(index) {
    http.get(urlArray[index], function(response){
        response.on('data', function(data){

            newData = data.toString();
            content[index] = content[index] + newData;
        })
        response.on('end', function(){
            count++;
            if (count === 3){
                printResults();
            }
        })
    })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    httpGet(i);
}
```

Common output is very close to what is expected, but includes an `undefined` string at the beginning and I can't figure out why.

```
undefinedLets get some ute when we're going parma. Grab us a slab how it'll be bull bar. He's got a massive bushie where stands out like a pot. 
undefinedShe'll be right mongrel heaps as cross as a hit the turps. Stands out like a booze also you little ripper flick. As stands out like ironman when lets throw a bikkie. 
undefinedHe hasn't got a bounce with gutful of struth. Stands out like a aerial pingpong piece of piss built like a battler.
```

As you can see, it's finding the array 'undefined' first, which is true, but then appending onto it.

My best guess is that it's the `content[index] = content[index] + newData;` line somehow holding on to the undefined nature of `let content = []` before `content[i]` is figured out. Now I've written it out and thought it through, this might be a simple JS problem I'm just overlooking or don't-know-that-I-don't-know.

Any help would be good.

Comment: Make sure to always declare your variables! `newData` isn't declared, so it is an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) can help avoid this and other kinds of errors. Getting in the habit of using a linter like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) can help improve your code a lot too.

Comment: Thank you, @UselessCode! I've been through this so many times figuring it out (I still don't quite have the logical-thinking for everything..). At one point it was declared, I've just moved a few things around. I suppose that highlights another 'check your work regardless' tip. (:

Answer (score 1):

Your getting right output, `content[index]` is undefined initially, you could do a undefined check, before concatenating `newData`. Here is complete code with changes.

```
const http = require('http');
const url = process.argv[2];

let content = [];
let count = 0;

const arguments = process.argv;
let urlArray = arguments.filter(function pullUrls(element, index, array) {
    return index >= 2;
});

function printResults() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(content[i]);
    }
}

function httpGet(index) {
    http.get(urlArray[index], function(response){
        response.on('data', function(data){

            let newData = data.toString();
            //check if undefined
            if(typeof content[index] !== 'undefined'){
              content[index] = content[index] + newData;
            }else{
              //add newData if undefined
              content[index] = newData;
            }

        })
        response.on('end', function(){
            count++;
            if (count === 3){
                printResults();
            }
        })
    })
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    httpGet(i);
}
```

Comment: In the exercise answer, they use the module `bl`, is it likely this does some kind of checking beforehand that I've neglected, or have I just written it in a way that *requires* checking?

Comment: That's not what `bl` module does, by using `bl` with callback, it returns complete data, which then stored like this `results[index] = data.toString()`, simply think of it like this `bl` doing the concatenation for you, where in your code you doing it yourself with `content[index] = content[index] + newData`, you need to check because initially `content[index]` is undefined initially.